# How to adopt the Woodbury matrix identity to this matrix formula

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

The [Woodbury matrix identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) is defined as follows:
$$
{(A+UCV)}^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}U{(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)}^{-1}VA^{-1}
$$

I want to use the Woodbury matrix identity theorem to change the following matrix formula
$$
W={(XX^T+\lambda G)}^{-1}XY
$$
into the following form
$$
W=G^{-1} X {(X^TG^{-1}X+\lambda I)}^{-1}Y
$$
The dimensions are as follows:
$$
X\in R^{p\times n}\\
G\in R^{p\times p}\\
Y\in R^{n\times c}
$$
Could anyone help give some hints?

UPDATE:

From the two formulas about $W$, we could get the following equations, thus the two $W$s should be equal:
[image]

Comment: It might help to give dimensions?

Comment: Hi, @copper.hat, I've updated the post. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you stated the identity correctly? The link has something different. (Missing parantheses on the left hand side)

Comment: Hi, @Max, thank you, I've revised the mistake.

Comment: @copper.hat, I've found the solution as posted in the answer. If you were interested, please check it. Thank you!

Comment: @Max, I've found the solution as posted in the answer. If you were interested, please check it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution as follows:

[image: My Derivation]

Comment: Yes, that looks correct to me.

Comment: Wow, nice job !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the different forms of W, as stated, are equivalent. For one thing, they do not appear to be  equivalent when the matrices involved are replaced by scalars. To illustrate, let $X=a$, $G=b$ and $Y=c$. Then,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
W{}={}{(XX^T+\lambda G)}^{-1}XY &{}\implies{}&W{}={}\frac{ac}{a^2{}+{}\lambda b}\,,\newline
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
while
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
W{}={}G^{-1} X {(X^TG^{-1}+\lambda I)}^{-1}Y &{}\implies{}&W{}={}\frac{ac}{a{}+{}\lambda b}\,.\newline
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Furthermore, direct manipulation of the first posted equation with $W$ gives
$$
W{}={}G^{-1} X {(X^TG^{-1}X+\lambda I)}^{-1}Y\,,
$$ 
which is different from the second $W$ equation posted but, now, seems consistent (assuming, in addition, that $X$ is invertible).

Comment: Hi, @ki3i, I'm very sorry that I've missed one $X$ in the second formula of $W$. I just found that fault.

Comment: @hubberwinston , I think you might have to verify the formulae you are interested in, carefully. In my derivation of $W$'s alternative form, I assumed that $X$ was invertible; this is clearly not the case, based on $X$ not being a square matrix.  So, I suspect the $W$ equations, as stated now, are still inconsistent.

Comment: thank you for your help! I've updated the post. Please check it. The $W$ equations should be consistent. But I still couldn't find the direct solution from the first $W$ to the second $W$.

Comment: @hubberwinston , The argument you show, starting from ${(XX^T+\lambda G)}^{-1}X {}={} G^{-1} X {(X^TG^{-1}X+\lambda I)}^{-1}$, does not follow from ${(XX^T+\lambda G)}^{-1}XY {}={}W{}={} G^{-1} X {(X^TG^{-1}X+\lambda I)}^{-1}Y$ since the matrices multiplying $Y$ on either side are *not* necessarily invertible square matrices. I don't think the stated expressions for $W$ are equivalent without extra assumptions e.g. invertibility of $X$.

Comment: Hi, @ki3i, I've found the solution as posted in the answer. If you were interested, please check it. Thank you!